# How do I set Text Colour in QTextBrowser (Html)?? (PyQt)

Tags: html, css, pyqt, pyqt4, qtextbrowser

I am trying to set a font colour for Html text in a created `QTextBrowser`. I've used basic Html Commands to set paragraphs, change font size etc. but when it comes to setting font colour, it doesn't seem to work?

The code that I used is shown below:

```
self.key = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self)
        self.key.setHtml(
            """<h1>Key</h1>
            <body>
            <font colour="red">
            GREEN = Overall Progress is 80% or above
            YELLOW = Overall Progress between 65%-79%
            Orange = Overall Progress is 64% or below
            </font>
            </body>"""
            )
```

It makes `Key` a header (Bold and Enlarged) via the use of `<h1>` but using `colour tags` or evem `colour codes` (e.g.`#00ff00`) don't seem to work

Comment: It's `color` not `colour` ;)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color There's different ways of spelling color :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the correct property is named `color` not `colour`, with that in mind, I'd do away with the `font` element completely, [as its long since deprecated](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/html_401/html4-ref/article.php/3460291) and change your code to, e.g:

```
self.key = QtGui.QTextBrowser(self)
        self.key.setHtml(
            """<body>
            <h1>Key</h1>
            <div style='color:red;'>
            GREEN = Overall Progress is 80% or above
            YELLOW = Overall Progress between 65%-79%
            Orange = Overall Progress is 64% or below
            </div>
            </body>"""
            )
```

Even better would be to use an external stylesheet to move your CSS out of being inline, and then apply a class to the `div`. In addition, all elements should reside within the `body` tags, so you should also move your `h1` below `body`

With that in mind, I'm not familiar with `QTextBrowser` however.